# Analytic proof of open mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that if $w=f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ and $f'(z_0)\ne 0$, then
>   $z=f^{-1}(w)$ is analytic at $w_0=f(z_0)$ and
>   $$\frac{df^{-1}}{dw}(w)=\frac{1}{\frac{df}{dz}(z)}$$ for $w=w_0,
>  z=z_0.$

I got that, $f(z)$ has an inverse $f^{-1}(w)$ near $w_0$ since $\exists$ a neighborhood around $z_0$ such that $f$ is one-one and since $f'(z_0)\ne 0$, then $f$ is non-constant thus it has an open set.

But now how can I show that it is continuous and verify that $$\frac{df^{-1}}{dw}(w)=\frac{1}{\frac{df}{dz}(z)}$$ for $w=w_0,
 z=z_0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the Cauchy Integral Formula yet? Once you know $f^{-1}$ is analytic, then you can use the chain rule. :)

Comment: Yes I do, but how can I show that?

Comment: Here's a hint: What is $\dfrac 1{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_C \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)-w}dz$?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure?

Comment: Apply the Residue Theorem, if you've had it. You really need to show us what you know and how you've tried to do the problem. Otherwise, we have no way to guess viable approaches.

Comment: Ahh, I see now, thanks! One last question, how did you get the form to be $$\dfrac 1{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_C \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)-w}dz?$$

Comment: By knowing I wanted the $z$ where $f(z )=w$. :)

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand, but thanks a lot! I will go study some more to try and understand this completely.